# After commits squash old changes are visible

Tags: git

I'm working on a branch, let's name it `branch_X`.
I made a lot of commits on this branch, then rebased it to `branch_Y` instead of `master`. Now I want to squash all commits I made on `branch_X`.

After performing `git rebase -i branch_Y` I see this:

```
pick f286i92 commit1
pick 9eb5eo7 commit2
pick 6dje1f9 commit3
pick 21235f5 commit4
pick df3e511 commit5
```

So I replace commits to squash with `squash` and I have this:

```
pick f286i92 commit1
squash 9eb5eo7 commit2
squash 6dje1f9 commit3
squash 21235f5 commit4
squash df3e511 commit5
```

Nice, commits are squashed but there are conflicts in files.
I checked those files and it looks like the changes from `commit2` are here
but it's strange cause `commit3` remove all `commit2` lines.
I'm sure that those changes are not on `branch_Y`.

Any ideas how can I resolve this problem?
I want to just squash commits made by me and have up to date branch without conflicts.

Comment: You just changed `pick` to `squash`, that's it? You didn't add, reorder, or delete any commits? That shouldn't produce any merge conflicts. How odd.

Comment: That's it. Nothing more. It's strange to see changes I made at the first day of this branch...